# Force absolute positioned div "behind" relative positioned div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create two offset borders around an image, one up and to the left, the other down and to the right, [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKCra.png)

With my current code, these outlines appear in front of the image. I'm wondering if there's a way to force them behind, or if anyone has a better way to go about this?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col" style="text-align:center">
      <div class="imagecontainer_staff">
         <img src="images/dodi_haug.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block" width="200" height="300" alt="Dodi Haug">
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.imagecontainer_staff {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.imagecontainer_staff::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3%;
    left: -3%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid cornflowerblue;
    content: '';
}

.imagecontainer_staff::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: +3%;
    left: +3%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: position:relative to the image and z-index:1 to the image (or a bigger value)

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't try to do it with a border in the first place. Use `shadow` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that work? I added `z-index` for `imagecontainer_staff::after`

```css
.imagecontainer_staff {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.imagecontainer_staff::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3%;
    left: -3%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid cornflowerblue;
    content: '';
}

.imagecontainer_staff::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: +3%;
    left: +3%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col" style="text-align:center">
      <div class="imagecontainer_staff">
         <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/dogecoin-doge-against-full-moon-260nw-1909080796.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block"               width="200" height="300" alt="Dodi Haug">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Could you please choose it accepted as accepted answer since it solved your problem, you are welcome :)